# What's the differece between these two sentences?

Tags: difference

1. My entire skin is green.
2. My skin is entirely green.
   Can sentence 1 mean my skin is partially green?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's very little difference in meaning here.  One uses an adjective to modify "skin" to indicate that all of the skin is green.  The second uses an adverb to indicate that the green colour applies to all the skin.

With other adjective/adverb pairs there can be a difference. Consider

> My new skin is green
>
> My skin is newly green.

The first applies to a new skin (not the old one). The second means my skin has recently changed colour. But in your example the meaning is the same.